# Disable code splitting (chunks) in Vue.js + Vite.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, rollupjs, vite

How I can disable chunking in Vue.js + [Vite.js](https://vitejs.dev) using [Rollup.js](https://rollupjs.org) on building project?

I tried like this but doesn't work for me:

```
export default defineConfig({
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            output: {
                manualChunks: {}
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: According to this [discussion in Rollup Issues](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/2756) I don't think it is possible.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me (for React, I think it should also work for Vue):

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite' // 2.8.0
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react' // 1.0.7

export default defineConfig ({
  plugins: [react()],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        manualChunks: {}
      },
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: Doesn't work with @preact/preset-vite