# How do I completely disable chunking in Vite and Rollup?

Tags: laravel, vite, rollup

I'm back in Laravel development after being out of practice since 2019ish. I'm more accustomed to Mix than to Vite but I like the @vite helpers in Blade. For this app I have to provide a Firebase service worker in the root public directory, accessible at https://example.com/firebase-messaging-sw.js. This is what my vite.config.js looks like:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            valetTls: 'whatever.test',
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
                'resources/js/firebase-messaging-sw.js'
            ],
            refresh: true,
        })
    ]
});
```

The problem is that firebase-messaging-sw.js uses import statements to grab Firebase functions from node_modules, which also end up in the compiled public-facing file as minified gibberish. Since a service worker isn't referenced as a module, "import" statements fail. ALL I want is for that file to be compiled into one single JavaScript file with no imports in the final product. This is trivially easy with Mix:

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.js('./build/firebase-messaging-sw.js', './public/firebase-messaging-sw.js');
```

But I'm already in too deep to switch to Mix at this point. What can I do to my configuration to make Vite output a single clean file, preferably without a hashed filename? I see [this](https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#output-manualchunks), but it assumes a much deeper knowledge of Rollup than I have, and I'm honestly not sure where the lines between Laravel/Vite/Rollup are drawn in this case. This seems like a very simple question but I can't find a recent answer.

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70258836/disable-code-splitting-chunks-in-vue-js-vite-js), I tried changing my vite.config.js to this:

```js
export default defineConfig({

    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
          output: {
            manualChunks: {}
          },
        }
    },

    plugins: [
        laravel({
            valetTls: 'whatever.test',
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
                'resources/js/firebase-messaging-sw.js'
            ],
            refresh: true,
        })
    ],

});
```

But this had no effect on Vite's output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can turn off chunking by dynamic imports with 'output.inlineDynamicImports: true`. The problem we have several inputs that doesn't support this options...

I didn't find any better solution than building the inputs separately:

- pass input file as an argument to vite-cli after `--` (Vite doesn't support custom arguments)
- dynamically change your Vite config to process only 1 input file at a time with inlineDynamicImports
- set `emptyOutDir: false` so a build wouldn't delete files built with another build.

---

The OP went with several config files which is a valid option too.
How this can be done:
[How to build multiple bundles using Vite similar to Multi Compiler mode(multi config) in Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76272727/how-to-build-multiple-bundles-using-vite-similar-to-multi-compiler-modemulti-co/76272803#76272803)

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

const input = process.argv[4]?.split('=')?.[1];
if (input) {
    console.log('SINGLE INPUT PROVIDED: ' + input);
}

export default defineConfig(() => {
    return {
        build: {
            emptyOutDir: false,
            rollupOptions: {
                input: input || ['main.js', 'test.js'],
                output: {
                    [input ? 'inlineDynamicImports' : 'dummy']: true,
                    entryFileNames: input || ['main.js', 'test.js']
                }
            },
        },
    };
});
```

My output:

```
printf "test.js main.js" | xargs -d ' ' -P0 -I% npx vite build -- --input=%
SINGLE INPUT PROVIDED: main.js
SINGLE INPUT PROVIDED: test.js
vite v4.3.9 building for production...
vite v4.3.9 building for production...
✓ 5 modules transformed.
✓ 3 modules transformed.
dist/test.js  0.95 kB │ gzip: 0.59 kB
dist/assets/javascript-8dac5379.svg  1.00 kB │ gzip: 0.60 kB
dist/assets/vite-4a748afd.svg        1.50 kB │ gzip: 0.77 kB
dist/assets/main-48a8825f.css        1.24 kB │ gzip: 0.65 kB
dist/main.js                         0.75 kB │ gzip: 0.43 kB
✓ built in 67ms
✓ built in 68ms
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, this gets me most of the way there. Using any of those suggestions causes this error: `Invalid value for option "output.inlineDynamicImports" - multiple inputs are not supported when "output.inlineDynamicImports" is true.`. Commenting out my other input files results in a correctly-compiled serviceworker js file that's exactly what I needed. How do I configure Vite/rollup to apply that change ONLY to resources/js/firebase-messaging-sw.js?

Comment: @politicoder that's a very interesting question, indeed! let me investigate... meanwhile you could accept my question (the checkbox) so i'll be motivated to dig deeper. I'll setup a new Vite project with multiple inputs...

Comment: @politicoder what code causes your service-worker.js to split? dynamic imports like `await import()` ? could you import statically?

Comment: Sure, in my userland code, the only import statements in firebase-messaging-sw.js are static ones at the top to import functions from Firebase's npm package. it's all `"import {x} from 'firebase/x'` type stuff, although I suppose dynamic import()s could be happening within Firebase's node modules.

Comment: @politicoder found the solution, editing the answer

Comment: Beautiful, thank you very much. I went with the two config file solution. All I would add for future readers is if you do this, also remember to put `build: {emptyOutDir: false}` in both config files so they don't delete each other's outputs. Thanks again!

Comment: @politicoder will add `build: {emptyOutDir: false}`

Comment: @politicoder my multi config command: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76272727/how-to-build-multiple-bundles-using-vite-similar-to-multi-compiler-modemulti-co/76272803#76272803