How do I get 'script.js' and 'style.css' in Quasar Framework v2 SPA mode - Vue 3 - Vite?
I am using Quasar CLI (pnpm create quasar) with these versions:
 Build mode............. spa
 Pkg quasar............. v2.17.0
 Pkg @quasar/app-vite... v1.10.0
 Pkg vite............... v2.9.18

When I run quasar build in the terminal, with the default configuration in quasar.config.js, I get multiple .js and .css files:
 UI files build summary:
 ╔═════════════════════════════════════════════╤═══════════╤══════════╗
 ║                                       Asset │      Size │  Gzipped ║
 ╟─────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────┼──────────╢
 ║               assets/AuthLayout.1d4d9575.js │   6.65 KB │  2.78 KB ║
 ║            assets/ErrorNotFound.abb8fc67.js │   0.55 KB │  0.38 KB ║
 ║                     assets/Home.f2a23ea1.js │   0.29 KB │  0.24 KB ║
 ║                   assets/Verify.1c0a8115.js │   0.29 KB │  0.24 KB ║
 ║            assets/cardContainer.4deff873.js │  92.98 KB │ 30.73 KB ║
 ║                    assets/index.54e093be.js │ 147.39 KB │ 55.63 KB ║
 ║ assets/plugin-vue_export-helper.21dcd24c.js │   0.09 KB │  0.10 KB ║
 ╟─────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────┼──────────╢
 ║           assets/cardContainer.b99046c2.css │   1.89 KB │  0.61 KB ║
 ║                   assets/index.d03be0f4.css │ 197.60 KB │ 34.79 KB ║
 ╟─────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────┼──────────╢
 ║                                  index.html │   0.87 KB │        - ║
 ╚═════════════════════════════════════════════╧═══════════╧══════════╝

I have tried extending the Vite configuration with no different results:
extendViteConf(viteConf) {
        viteConf = {
          build: {
            rollupOptions: {
              output: {
                inlineDynamicImports: true,
              },
            },
          },
        };
      },

What should I do to get only one .js file and one .css file in Quasar/Vite?
I am trying to get a single .js file and a single .css file when I run quasar build in the terminal.
I hope to find out what configuration I need to make in quasar.config.js.
Edit: code with pretty format.

You are probably looking for disabling chunks on build. Seems to be a bit tricky as it is not the "state of the art", but you can have a look towards this build setup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76517758/how-do-i-completely-disable-chunking-in-vite-and-rollup
